# Finding A Collective Average & Letter Grade For Tests & Assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I am using Python 3.4.1 and I am trying to write a code that does the following:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name, self.grades = name, []

    def append_grade(self, grade):
        self.grades.append(grade)

    def average(self):
        return sum(self.grades) / len(self.grades)

    def letter_grade(self):
        average = self.average()
        for value, grade in (90, "A"), (80, "B"), (70, "C"), (60, "D"):
            if average >= value:
                return grade
        else:
            return "F"

def main():
    print()
    a_class = []  # "class" by itself is a reserved word in Python, avoid using
    while True:
        print()
        print('{} students in class so far'.format(len(a_class)))
        another_student = input('Do you have another student to enter (y/n) ? ')
        if another_student[0].lower() != 'y':
            break
        print()
        student_name = input('What is the student\'s ID? ')
        a_class.append(Student(student_name))
        print()
        print('student :', student_name)
        print('------------------------------------------------')
        number_of_tests = int(input('Please enter the number of tests : '))
        for test_num in range(1, number_of_tests+1):
            print('test grade {}'.format(test_num), end='')
            score = float(input(' : '))
            if score < 0:  # stop early?
                break
        number_of_assignments = int(input('Please enter the number of assignments : '))
        for assignment_num in range(1, number_of_assignments+1):
            print('assignment grade {}'.format(assignment_num), end='')
            score2 = float(input(' : '))
            if score2 < 0:  # stop early?
                break
        number_of_participation = int(input('Please enter 1 to add participation grade : '))
        for participation_num in range(1, number_of_participation+1):
            print('participation grade {}'.format(participation_num), end='')
            score3 = float(input(' : '))
            if score3 < 0:  # stop early?
                break

            a_class[-1].append_grade(score + score2 + score3) # append to last student added

    print_report(a_class)

def print_report(a_class):
    print()
    print('Student Grades')
    print()
    for student in sorted(a_class, key=lambda s: s.name):
        print('student: {:20s} average test score: {:3.2f}  grade: {}'.format(
            student.name, student.average(), student.letter_grade()))
    print()
    print('The class average is {:.2f}'.format(class_average(a_class)))

def class_average(a_class):
    return sum(student.average() for student in a_class) / len(a_class)

main()
```

The task here is to get the letter grade of a student by adding 3 different things and getting the average. I need to be able to input the test scores, assignment scores, and 1 participation grade. Those need to average out and give me a final letter grade. I was able to find out how to do just one set of scores to average but when I added the other scores, the average is wrong. What can I edit here?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and cut this down to a minimal, correctly-formatted example. Also, please provide a better error description than *"the average is wrong"* - what were the inputs and expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Indentation is crucial in Python, but you managed to lose most of it in your post. Can you at the very least fix that?

Comment: Next, you need to tell us *what* goes wrong. What inputs? What are the outputs you expected? What did you get instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have fixed the indentation to match what I have in my code. When I run the program I do not get an error however. Its supposed to take the grades that I input, so for example, 2 tests (89,75), 2 Assignments (95,78), and 1 participation grade (65) and then average them all out. The number I get for the average is over 100 which is obviously wrong. I do not understand why it is doing that since I am not getting an error message anywhere specific in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look in great detail, but this:

```
a_class[-1].append_grade(score + score2 + score3)
```

...makes me suspect that you are adding a single value to the list of grades, that is above 100%.  That might account for your averages being too high.

Instead, you likely should:

```
a_class[-1].append_grade(score)
a_class[-1].append_grade(score2)
a_class[-1].append_grade(score3)
```